# How to Execute Multiple Insertion Error Happend RollBack Inserted Table in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, try-catch

This is my code. How to avoid error happened any query automatically rollback already stored.

```
insert into muser(UserKey, Email, UserPassword) 
values(@Key, @Useremail, 'test')

set @UserId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
set @Key = NEWID()

insert into  mUserProfile(UserProfileKey, UserId, UserEmail)
values(@Key, @UserId, @Useremail)

exec SP_Store @Useremail, @ClientId,
```

Comment: don't quite understand what you're asking. are you just asking about putting your code in a transaction and rolling back? check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188929.aspx

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear but I think you want something along these lines.

```
begin transaction

begin try

    insert into muser(UserKey,Email,UserPassword) 
    values(@Key,@Useremail,'test')

    set @UserId= SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    set @Key =NEWID()


    insert into  mUserProfile(UserProfileKey,UserId,UserEmail)
    values(@Key,@UserId,@Useremail)

    exec SP_Store @Useremail,@ClientId --You should avoid the SP_ prefix. 

    commit transaction
end try
begin catch
    --Report the error here, do NOT silently rollback you transaction
    rollback transaction
end catch
```

This should work with one caveat. If you have a transaction is SP_Store this is not going to work correctly because you can't nest transactions in sql server.

Also, you really avoid the SP_ prefix, or even better avoid prefixes entirely. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix